# SQL select no result

Tags: sql

The SQL below returns no result but there is one record in the table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ul.* FROM UserLogin ul, ContactPerson cp, UserRole url, Role rl
```

If I run this query, it returns the record:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ul.* FROM UserLogin ul
```

Can you help explain this and how to make the first one work?

Comment: What do you want the first query to return? Sounds like you need a WHERE to join the tables up, or some JOINs. More details please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're pulling from 4 different tables:

UserLogin
ContactPerson
UserRole
Role

You need to do either a [UNION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) all or a [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp), otherwise most of the time it will return blank.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
SELECT distinct ul.* 
  FROM UserLogin ul
```

...works because it is selecting from a single table, while this:

```
SELECT distinct ul.* 
  FROM UserLogin ul,
       ContactPerson cp,
       UserRole url,
       Role rl
```

...is using non ANSI JOIN syntax to join the `USERLOGIN`, `CONTACTPERSON`, `USERROLE` and `ROLE` tables together.  In order for records to be returned from the query, there has to be records that exist in all tables involved.  To visualize it, it would look like this:

[image]

The blue portion represents the records that would be returned from a query similar to yours.

To get records from all those tables, we have to know how they relate to one another.

Here is an example of your query using ANSI join syntax, including assumptions on how the tables relate in order to get the query to return results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ul.*
  FROM CONTACTPERSON cp
  JOIN USERLOGIN ul ON ul.user_id = cp.user_id
  JOIN USERROLE ur ON ur.user_id = ul.user_id
  JOIN ROLE r ON r.role_id = ur.role_id
```

It's not clear what the relationship between USERLOGIN and CONTACTPERSON are...

I highly recommend reading this [article on SQL JOINs](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/).

### ANSI vs Non ANSI JOIN syntax

ANSI JOIN syntax is recommended - it's more readable, separates the actual `WHERE` clause criteria from the JOIN criteria, and is supported across various databases making queries more likely to be portable.

Comment: thanks very much for the detailed explanation,but JOIN can't return the result i want, so i went to UNION and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join all the tables ul, cp, url, rl. For example

```
SELECT distinct ul.* FROM UserLogin ul join ContactPerson cp
on ul.id=cp.user
```

Comment: For more help on Joins check out http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000976.html

Comment: No - that's old style SQL (SQL-86); there's a cartesian product between the 4 tables listed.

Answer (score 1):

Your SELECT statement lists 4 tables and does a cartesian product of them.

Since the SELECT returns no rows, one of the tables must be empty.

Since you assert that table UserLogin contains one row, at least one of the other three tables must be empty.